# ggplot2 error when attemping to plot a violin graph using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to create a violin plot of lengths generated by two different software. Whenever I attempt to generate the plot I am met with the following error:

```
  X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 11 could not be loaded
```

I've scoured the internet, but the only thing I could find was a 'polygone edge not detected' error that begins similarly to my error message, but does not fix the problem.

Any advice?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/496488).

Comment: It's just a simple plot, the x is the name of the software, and the y is a column of lengths. The problem is unique to my computer and I am able to plot the same graph on my laptop, just not on my desktop.

Comment: I got quite a few hits on "ubuntu r face 1 at size 11 could not be loaded", and some of the first ones look like they might contain useful info.  See, e.g., [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Some-problems-with-X11-td820171.html) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449578/x11-font-adobe-helvetica-s-s-d-face-2-at-size-11-could-no)